# JavaFX ImageIO.write() doesn't save modified BufferedImage

Tags: java, javafx, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm trying to create an application that lets users modify pictures and then save them. I'm having trouble with the saving part.

This is the method that rotates the picture:

```
public void process(ImageView imageView) {
    if(imageView.getImage() != null){
        BufferedImage img;
        img = Home.img;
        double rads = Math.toRadians(90);
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);
        int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

        BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);

        int x = w / 2;
        int y = h / 2;

        at.rotate(rads, x, y);
        g2d.setTransform(at);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0,null);
        g2d.dispose();
        imageView.setImage(convertToFxImage(rotated));
        Home.img = rotated;
    }
}
```

It sets the image in the `Home` controller class's imageView and also sets a static field to the modified image. Then I try to save it inside the `Home` class:

```
savAs.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            File dir = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(opButton.getScene().getWindow());
            if (dir != null) {
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(img, dir.getAbsolutePath().substring(dir.getAbsolutePath().length() - 3), dir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This for some reason doesn't work. No `IOException` is thrown, but it doesn't create any file. When I try to save without modifying the image it works. Any idea why?

Comment: You don't need swing to rotate an image.  [ImageView javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) provides an example of rotating an image.  [Rotate the ImageView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setRotate(double)) which holds the image.

Comment: When you want to save it, [snapshot it](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)), [convert to a BufferedImage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#fromFXImage(javafx.scene.image.Image,java.awt.image.BufferedImage)), then [write it to a file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.File)).

Comment: If you still have issues, update your question with a complete, executable (by copy and paste) [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in `ImageIO` you call is specified below and it returns a boolean status code that you ignore:

```
public static boolean write(RenderedImage im,
                            String formatName,
                            File output) throws IOException
```

You haven't included details of the File so there is no way of telling if you have passed in a valid `formatName` which you derive from the last three characters of the output filename. Note that `formatName` isn't always 3 characters and should be lowercase - so both "FILE.JPG" and "FILE.JPEG" may fail to save.

If you believe the file extension is correct and is supported by the `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` format you've used, try change to use lowercase format, then check the result:

```
String format = dir.getAbsolutePath().substring(dir.getAbsolutePath().length() - 3).toLowerCase();
boolean ok = ImageIO.write(img, format, dir);
if (!ok)
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to write "+format+" to " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

If the `BufferedImage` format isn't compatible with the file extension, try using `new BufferedImage(... , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)` or a different format type (eg PNG).

Comment: Thak you! I had to change BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB to BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB